# PDFSharp live designer

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp to create my PDFs.
Though it is very annoying to rebuild and run the project everytime so that I can see my changes. It just takes a lot of time which is not very efficient.
So I thought that maybe there is like a live designer in which I can write code and see the changes right away. There is a lot of that for CSS and HTML.
I am also open to any other sort of stuff that means designing reports a lot easier.

Comment: There's no such thing for PDFSharp. Only iText has something that corresponds with your description. It's called [iText DITO](http://dito.online/). DITO is short for Design Interactive Templates Online. It's an in-browser WYSIWYG designer that allows you to create a template using drag-and-drop. The result is a `.dito` file that is actually a ZIP file containing HTML, CSS, resources (images, fonts,..) and information about the data binding. You can import JSON data in the designer to see what a populated template would look like.

Comment: Thanks, I am very happy with iText 7 from what I saw and I tried some stuff already. Could you help me with my other question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657991/itext-7-return-pdf-from-asp-net-webapi @BrunoLowagie